# Counting page transfers between disk and main memory

Tags: arrays, paging, virtual-memory

```
for I := 1 to 1024 do
    for J := 1 to 1024 do
        A[J,I] := A[J,I] * B[I,J]
```

For the given code, I want to count how many pages are transferred between disk and main memory given the following assumptions:

- page size = 512 words
- no more than 256 pages can be in main memory
- LRU replacement strategy
- all 2d arrays size (1:1024,1:1024)
- each array element occupies 1 word
- 2d arrays are mapped in main memory in row-major order

I was given the solution, and my questions stems from that:

> A[J,I] := A[J,I] * B[I,J]
>
> writeA := readA  *  readB
>
> Notice that there are 2 transfers changing every J loop and 1 transfer
>   that only changes every I loop.
>
> 1024 * (8 + 1024 * (1 + 1)) = 2105344 transfers
>
> So the entire row of B is read every time we use it, therefore we
>   count the entire row as transferred (8 pages). But since we only read
>   a portion of each A row (1 value) when we transfer it, we only grab 1
>   page each time.

So what I'm trying to figure out is, how do we get that 8 pages are transferred every time we read B but only 1 transfer for each read and write of A?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised you're confused, because I certainly am.

Part of the confusion comes from labelling the arrays 1:1024. I couldn't think like that, I relabelled them 0:1023.

I take "row-major order" to mean that A[0,0] is in the same disk block as A[0,511]. The next block is A[0,512] to A[0,1023]. Then A[1,0] to A[1,511]... And the same arrangement for B.

As the inner loop first executes, the system will fetch the block containing A[0,0], then B[0,0]. As J increments, each element of A referenced will come from a separate disk block. A[1,0] is in a different block from A[0,0]. But only every 512th B element referenced will come from a different block; B[0,0] is in the same block as B[0,511]. So for one complete iteration through the inner loop, 1024 calculations, there will be 1024 fetches of blocks from A, 1024 writes of dirty blocks from A, and 2 fetches of blocks from B. 2050 accesses overall. I don't understand why the answer you have says there will be 8 fetches from B. If B were not aligned on a 512-word boundary, there would be 3 fetches from B per cycle; but not 8.

This same pattern happens for each value of I in the outer loop. That makes 2050*1024 = 2099200 total blocks read and written, assuming B is 512-word aligned.

I'm entirely prepared for someone to point out my obvious bloomer - they usually do - but the explanation you've been given seems wrong to me.

Comment: I was thinking B would be 2 and A 1, this whole question is confusing and I've pretty much moved on at this point. Thanks for the attempt

Comment: I think maybe I should clarify what he means by row-major order.  Row-major order refers to the way the compiler maps a 2d array into memory.  Row-major will fill a row before going to the next column.  Column-major would be the opposite, it will fill a column before moving to the next column.